# Adjacent Sibling Selectors CSS - is it possible to group them?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't really find any information on my problem, mainly because I don't know enough about CSS to word the search query properly, so sorry if it's been asked.

I'm trying to group adjacent sibling selectors in the following way so that any header that follows any other element will have the given margins:

```
.box * + h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    margin-bottom:0.35em;
    margin-top:1em;
}
```

This is apparently wrong because all headings remain very close to preceding elements. Is it possible to do something like this, or do I have to specify each heading individually? I even tried brackets around the heading selectors...

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<div id="work" class="box">
    <h3>5. Once you're happy with your application, send it off to the employer!</h3>
    <h4>Important Stuff to Remember:</h4>
    <p>If you're sending your application by post, you should put a paperclip in the upper left-
    hand corner of your CV to hold it together (do the same thing with the application form if
    there is one), then put your application documents in an A4 envelope (don't fold them) in the
    following order:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>1. Application form (if applicable) at the bottom</li>
        <li>2. Then the CV</li>
        <li>3. Then the cover letter on top (i.e, covering the other documents)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your HTML, please? Also, assuming you are selecting the elements correctly, this should only work for the `h1`. You need to repeat `.box * + h2` for all of them. Consider using something like LESS if you want to avoid that.

Comment: Maybe you mean `.box * + h1, .box * + h2` and so on?

Comment: Adding on to Josh's comment, the current code would select all `h2` (and the other headings) like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uhvnepem/). Only for `h1` it will respect the combination.

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks guys. I thought there would be a cute shorthand.

Comment: Welcome mate :) But if you really want to style all headings with that combination, the best would be `.box * + .headings` (setting class for all `h*` tags as `headings`)

Comment: directly select the children. `.box>h2,.box>h2,.box>h3,.box>h4{
   color:#900;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write it like this:

```
 .box *+h1, .box *+h2, .box *+h3, .box *+h4, .box *+h6, .box *+h6 {
     margin-bottom:0.35em;
     margin-top:1em;
 }
```

This will result in: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1qfez0e9/1/). (I made the affected headers green)

Your old code would have selected all h2, h3 and h4 - tags, so also outside the div, as well as the first header in the div. Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1qfez0e9/2/)